# Is than any better way for Round corners for Div with jquery.corner.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using jquery corner for making a div round cornered. But the problem I am facing is that when the background of that rounded div is a gradient, it is showing some odd colors in the corners.

I want to know any other better way for including round corners for div

EDIT 1:

$(".nav").corner("20");

This code im using for the round corner of 20 px

Comment: I would recommend showing an example of the code that you are using, and a screenshot of the effect you are seeing (or link to small example that others can test), as well as mentioning which browsers you have already tested. As it is, your question is a little vague.

Comment: Help yourself
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356756/rounded-corners-on-divs-without-using-images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846962/round-corners-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know any other better way for including round corners for div

The "best" way in the near future will be **CSS3** which provides designers the ability to give border-radius settings like for example here: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/.

The downside of it is that it's at the moment not supported by current browsers but that's also explained in that article.

Comment: I would do this as well. It works in most browsers except IE < v9. IE users can just accept it won't look as good and give them a good reason to upgrade!